# mount share cifs folder without sudo

Tags: permissions, mount, cifs

I want to mount share folder.
Curren command line:

```bsh
sudo mount -t cifs -o username=USERNAME,password=PASSWD
```

Is it have some safe way (without permanent sudo and other). Any others utils?

If this is not possible in general, it will be enough for me to be able to mount only a certain shared folder to a certain place.

Comment: You want to run that command without sudo?

Comment: I want to run ANY command that not require root access and mount cifs with name and password

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To be able to mount that folder as a normal user, include the mount options for the cifs folder in the configuration file /etc/fstab, and add the options `noauto,user`, similar to:

```
//nas-server/cifsShare /media/user/cifsShare cifs -o username=<username>,noauto,user 0 0
```

The option `noauto` will make sure the drive is not mounted during startup, but will nevertheless register all parameters necessary to mount the drive. The option `user` will allow any user to mount the drive.

With this setup, any user is able to mount the share with the `mount` command, followed by the path that was specified in fstab where the folder is to be mounted, e.g.

```
mount /media/user/cifsShare
```

or followed by the share, as in

```
mount //nas-server/cifsShare
```

Easier, probably, will be to mount the share using the file manager (Files in standard Ubuntu 18.04). In standard Files, one mounts a drive by providing the URI, in the form of

`smb://server/share`

A dialog will pop up to ask login, domain and password. Optionally, these settings can be remembered. You can subsequently make a bookmark for easy one-click access in the future.

This works out of the box in several editions of Ubuntu (stock Ubuntu, but also Kubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) and avoids the need to change system configuration files.

Comment: I use ubuntu from ssh. GUI is not available for me.

Comment: @vanadium, You might want to show a generic fstab entry in your answer with the noauto,user combination so that it is more obvious. Then to mount the share all Hait would have to do is issue a "mount /mountpoint" - without sudo just as you described.

Comment: Is it right? //<ip_addres>/<resource>   /media/<mount_point>/ cifs [user=username>@<domain>],[password=<password>],noauto,user  0 0

Comment: As Morbius suggested, I edited the answer to add a generic fstab entry for improving clarity. GUI not available was not clear for the question. It does not harm to leave that part in.

Comment: The `-o` won't parse on my Debian buster system

Comment: What would the syntax for this be if instead of specifying the username on the command line, we're using a credentials file?

Answer (score 8):

Wanted to add a comment, but I do not have enough rep.

On Ubuntu 20 I got syntax errors when trying to add above mentioned entry:

```
//nas-server/cifsShare /media/user/cifsShare cifs -o username=<username>,noauto,user 0 0
```

here is what worked for me:

```
//192.168.1.106/repos /home/ubuntu/shared-repos  cifs username=<user>,noauto,user 0 0
```

`-o` was the offending party.

Comment: I edited the original answer as it was indeed wrong in this respect.  Thank you for pointing this out - it saved me some time!

Comment: You can use `user=` instead of `username=`. There's also `pass=` for pw. See [man mount.cifs](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) for more details.

Comment: Yep, _/etc/fstab_ is already table with headers named in commented line.