Write to mounted NAS without sudo permission?
The goal is to write to a synology NAS without sudo.  SAMBA permissions are read / write with the user mySambaName.   Mount command required sudo:
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.x.y/home /home/username/nas -o username=mySambaName

Reading from the mounted directory returns the contents of the NAS, however, my observation was that sudo is required to write a text file:
sudo vi /home/username/nas/text.txt

The command   chown -c username:username /home/username/nas
failed to change the owner/group from root to username.
What needs to be done be able to write without sudo permission?
Is the solution to somehow not use sudo to mount and somehow configure /etc/fstab?

You should be able to use gio mount to mount using fuse... (https://askubuntu.com/a/1406162/631600)  Or put it with options noauto,user in your fstab. (https://askubuntu.com/q/1100114/631600)

I use a Synology NAS extensively and have no issues writing files of all types to it and without the need for superuser privileges. EG For my user share I have the following entry in my ~/etc/fstab file //192.168.1.117/homes/Graham /media/NAS/Graham cifs username=user,password=psw,rw,uid=1000,gid=500 The synology drives are formatted ext4 in an SHR raid. Those credentials are for the NAS share, not my Linux user account

@graham   Thank you for the inspiring reply!  I'd like to understand how uid=1000 and gid=500 were assigned.

Someone else asked me that question before and I don't know the reasoning behind it. I think it came from a post elsewhere, I tried it and it worked so on the basis "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" I left it as it was. I believe that 1000, 1000 will work just as well. The gid is of course Group ID but as there is only one user on the system.... I hope that helps.

BTW replace "user" with the NAS share username and "psw" with the NAS' user password - but you knew that already...

CIFS - as in mount.cifs - creates a virtual filesystem on the client and by default will mount with owner=group=root with permissions of 755. Only root has write access.
mount.cifs gives you the ability to change ownership or permissions - on the client - to anything you want.
SO you can replace root as owner to you by using the uid option, for example:
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.x.y/home /home/username/nas -o username=mySambaName,uid=1000

If your uid on the client is 1000. Run id to verify
You can also use your linux login user name instead of 1000. So for me ( morbius ) if would be:
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.x.y/home /home/username/nas -o username=mySambaName,uid=morbius

Either way now I as owner can write to the mounted share.
There are many options available to you. You could for example go to the opposite extreme and make it writeable to everyone on the client machine:
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.x.y/home /home/username/nas -o username=mySambaName,uid=morbius,nounix,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0666

